# OpenFeign Builder default client

Tags: feign, openfeign

What is the default Client used by Openfeign Builder.

**OkHttp client**

```
Feign.builder().client(new feign.okhttp.OkHttpClient()).target(SomeData.class,"http://test.com");
```

**What is the default client?**

```
Feign.builder().target(SomeData.class,"http://test.com");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's still relevant for you:

If you look at [the source code of Feign.Builder](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/core/src/main/java/feign/Feign.java#L102), you'd see that it uses `Client.Default` unless otherwise specified.

`Client.Default` [is actually a good old Java HTTP Client](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/core/src/main/java/feign/Client.java#L58) from `java.net` package.

If you're not familiar with it, you can read about it in [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html).